# In Mahout, is there any method for data classification with Naive Bayes?

Tags: mahout

I am still a newbie in using Mahout, and currently studying on the Naive Bayes for data classification.

As far as I know Mahout has 2 related programs, one is `trainnb` which is for training Bayes model, and `testnb` which is for evaluating the model. Under current implementation of Mahout, is there a way to apply the model on new data classification by just a simple command? Or do I need to code an implementation from scratch (e.g. use the model as a base to calculate the likelihood for each of the possibilities, compute and return the class with highest value) using java?

Comment: What has this to do with R?

Comment: Excuse me, just aiming at finishing the task with Mahout only. Thanks.